# Using Puppet's new firewall module, how do I clear iptables before rules are applied?

Tags: linux, iptables, puppet

I am currently using Puppet's new [firewall module](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/firewall). I am trying to have Puppet flush `iptables` before it applies firewall rules. I tried the following:

```
exec { 'clear-firewall':
        command => '/sbin/iptables -F',
        refreshonly => true,
}

Firewall {
        subscribe => Exec['clear-firewall'],
        notify => Exec['persist-firewall'],
}
```

So far, it has not worked. Can anyone suggest or know of another method I should try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I imagine you are in one of two situations:

1. You have existing rules you wish to flush because you want the
   puppet configuration to own your firewall rules
2. You have existing rules that are not compatible with the firewall provider

If its 1 ... just try turning on purge somewhere in top scope:

```
resources { "firewall":
  purge => true,
}
```

If its 2 ... you will probably need to purge those rules or make them compatible before puppet runs. If you have a particular incompatibility let me know - we should probably get a bug raised on it.

Comment: Situation 1. And thank you! I will test it this evening. Did not see that in the documentation (`puppet describe firewall`).

Comment: In my manifests, I have that in `site.pp` but Puppet is still not purging the firewall rules.

Comment: @Rob sounds like a bug.

Comment: @KenBarber I think it is. https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-firewall/issues/259